# Email input value come undefined on alert using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have form which contain email input field

```
<form id="TypeValidation" action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <div class="form-group has-label col-sm-6">
        <label>
            Email
        </label>
        <input class="form-control" name=email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-center">
              <button type="submit" name="add_usr_acc" id="add_usr_acc" value="add_usr_acc" class="btn btn-primary" >Add</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Issue is that in script code when alert on email then come undefined. how to get value in which user type a email

```
  <script>
    $("#TypeValidation").on('submit', (function(e) {
      var email = $(this).find('input[name="email"]').val();
      alert(email); {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: "fn_acc_submit.php?addUsraccID=" + addUsraccID,
          type: "POST",
          data: new FormData(this),
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          dataType: "html",
          beforeSend: function() {
            $("#add_usr_acc").prop('disabled', 'disabled')
          },
          success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
            location.reload();
            if (result == '1') {
              location.replace("lst_user_account.php");

            } else {
              location.replace("add_user_account.php");

            }
          }
        });
      }
    }));
  </script>
```

Please fix my problem where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you may find it easier to debug when you indent your code properly, that way you can see where all the blocks are at a glance without counting up brackets and such.

Comment: You are missing a double quote in name attribute, `<input class="form-control" name=email" type="email" required>`

Comment: Missing the open quote on the name attribute of your email field.

Comment: oops.. Missing the open quote.. now its working on alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your HTML code at below line:

```
    <input class="form-control" name=email" type="email" required>
```

Here `name=email"` is not valid.

Change this to `name="email"`

Answer (score 2):

In you input field, it should name="email". You forgot to add opening quotes.